# How can I insert a variable containing a backslash in sed?

Tags: bash, sed, escaping, backslash

Please see these simple commands:

```
$ echo $tmp
UY\U[_
$ echo "a" | sed "s|a|${tmp}|g"
UY[_
```

The `\U` is eaten. Other backslashes won't survive either.

How can I make the above command work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only backslash that is "eaten" by sed and escaping just that is enough, then try:

```
echo "a" | sed "s|a|${tmp//\\/\\\\}|g"
```

Confusing enough for you? `\\` represents a single \ since it needs to be escaped in the shell too.
The inital `//` is similar to the `g` modifier in `s/foo/bar/g`, if you only want the first occurring pattern to be replaced, skip it.

The docs about `${parameter/pattern/string}` is available here: http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

**Edit:** Depending on what you want to do, you might be better of not using sed for this actually.

```
$ tmp="UY\U[_"
$ in="a"
$ echo ${in//a/$tmp}
UY\U[_
```

Comment: i picked this solution. thank you! i am using sed to process files. the cryptic string is encoded password.

Answer (score 1):

You could reparse $tmp itself through sed

```
echo "a" | sed "s|a|$(echo ${tmp} | sed 's|\\|\\\\|g')|g"
```

Comment: i tried this solution, got this: $ echo $tmp
A\UB
$ echo "a" | sed "s|a|$(echo ${tmp} | sed 's|\\|\\\\|g')|g"
A\UB
not sure. i picked the other solution because it needs less pipes and sed's. i still appreciate your answer.